# Feature selection using XGBoost, should I add the gains of different CV folds to choose the best N features?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, feature-selection

Trying to understand if this is the right approach, without being able to find much through conventional googling.

Using XGB, if i have pretty wide data, and I want to choose say, the best 300 (out of say, 1000) features to build my model on, I understand that I should separate the test and train set, and divide the TRAIN set only to create my k-folds. (i.e. dont feature select on the entire dataset.)

How does one use the feature importances from each of the k-folds to select the top n features to use? Do I simply sum the normalised gains for each feature over the folds, and choose the n with the highest sum(normalized_gains)? Or is it best to just follow the k-fold that minimised the error?

Comment: I think this belongs to CrossValidated or DataScience part of StackExchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: As @Rafa mentioned, post this on StackExcahnge as it is not about programming and more about approach